# How to create Azure DevOps Service Connection scoped to multiple Resource Groups

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-pipelines, service-principal, serviceconnection

I have a project whose resources spanned across 3 resource groups. I want to create a Service connection scoped to all those resource groups so that i can manage access at one place through that service connection. Currently i created 3 service connections scoped to each resource group. I don't want to scope it to subscription since there are other teams handling projects in that subscription. It will give me maintenance and audit issues in the future.

If i create a service principal and assign it to 3 resource groups and then attach this service principal to service connection then would it be good design?

Is there any better way to achieve this ?

Comment: Hi ,Venky Is bbaywet's answer helpful to your issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to create the service principal manually. **You can use the interface to create the service principal, grant permissions on the first resource group and configure the connection automatically for you**.
Then once it's done, look at the service connection to identify the service principal in use, **and give it permissions on the other resource groups**.
And yes it is a good design, the only drawback compared to 3 service principals is that you **have less granularity over who in Azure DevOps has access to** each of these 3 resource groups via permissions on the service service connection(s) (as you only have one and not 3)

Comment: Thanks. Do you know anyway to automate all this process through powershell/cli/ARM?

Comment: I suggest you ask a separate question for this but you could use powershell to create app service principals https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/azurerm/create-azure-service-principal-azureps?view=azurermps-6.13.0 and assign it to the resource group. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/templates/101-rbac-builtinrole-resourcegroup/ Not sure how to automate the service connection part on ADO though

Comment: The only possible caution here is that if you Edit the connection via the Azure DevOps interface it may create a new ServicePrincipal and/or remove your extended permissions.

Answer (score 4):

When you create a new Service Connection in the Azure DevOps, it will create an Azure AD app registration, and a new service principal will be created for the Resource Group you choose.

[image]

[image]

So you can just go to any resource group and then add a principal using the Access control (IAM). Select the Add role assignment option and then select the role as a contributor in the role grid, press next. From the next screen, select user, group, or service principal as the option for Assign access to. Click on the + Select members, search for our AD Registered app name, the display name and then select the same from the result, click on the select button. Finally, click the Review + assign button.

[image]

I have written a detailed article to explain the steps, you can read that [here](https://sibeeshpassion.com/azure-devops-service-connection-with-multiple-azure-resource-group/).